# Inserting data stored in the session storage into MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm having trouble inserting data stored in the session storage into MongoDB. I've created an array to display the data into my HTML table, but I can't insert it into MongoDB.

```
<?php
//Extract the product IDs that were sent to the server
$prodIDs= $_POST['prodIDs'];

//Convert JSON string to PHP array 
$productArray = json_decode($prodIDs, true);

echo '<table id="basket_list">';
echo '<tr><th>Product Image</th><th>Product Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Count</th></tr>';
for($i=0; $i<count($productArray); $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="image_column"><img class="basket_img" src="' . $productArray[$i]['image'] . '"></td>';
    echo '<td>' . $productArray[$i]['name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="totalPrice">£' . $productArray[$i]['price'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $productArray[$i]['count'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

$mongoClient = new MongoClient();

$db = $mongoClient->ecommerce;

$collection = $db->orders;

//Convert to PHP array
$orderData = [
    "image" => $productArray["image"],  
    "name" => $productArray["name"], 
    "price" => $productArray["price"], 
    "count" => 1
];

//Add the order to the database
$returnVal = $collection->insert($orderData);

//Close the connection
$mongoClient->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$productArray` is multidimensional so you need to access it like `$productArray[<index>]["<attribute>"]`. You can also loop over it when you insert the data.

```
$mongoClient = new MongoClient();
$db = $mongoClient->ecommerce;
$collection = $db->orders;

for($i=0; $i<count($productArray); $i++) {

    //Convert to PHP array
    $orderData = [
        "image" => $productArray[i]["image"],  
        "name" => $productArray[i]["name"], 
        "price" => $productArray[i]["price"], 
        "count" => 1
    ];

    //Add the order to the database
    $returnVal = $collection->insert($orderData);

}

//Close the connection
$mongoClient->close();
```

Or to only access the first (or any other) single element.

```
$orderData = [
    "image" => $productArray[0]["image"],  
    "name" => $productArray[0]["name"], 
    "price" => $productArray[0]["price"], 
    "count" => 1
];
```